# Azure - nodejs serverless function throwing error Error: 13 INTERNAL: Failed to parse server response

Tags: node.js, azure

I am getting the below expeception, my node serverless function is throwing exception however many time it works correctly, when I check failed request, these exceptions are found.

```
Exception while executing function: Functions.createParticipantUserEntry node exited with code 1
     at Object.module.exports.exports.createStatusError (/azure-functions-host/workers/node/worker-bundle.js:980:15),
     details: 'Failed to parse server response',LanguageWorkerConsoleLog[error]
     Worker 78afd559-7c19-4b0d-9a60-9a3039049fe2 uncaught exception: Error: Error: 13 INTERNAL: Failed to parse server response
         at ClientDuplexStream.<anonymous> (/azure-functions-host/workers/node/worker-bundle.js:18483:19)     
         at ClientDuplexStream.emit (events.js:400:28)     
         at ClientDuplexStream._emitStatusIfDone (/azure-functions-host/workers/node/worker-bundle.js:7691:12)     
         at ClientDuplexStream._receiveStatus (/azure-functions-host/workers/node/worker-bundle.js:7668:8)     
         at Object.onReceiveStatus (/azure-functions-host/workers/node/worker-bundle.js:23065:15)     
         at InterceptingListener.module.exports.InterceptingListener._callNext (/azure-functions-host/workers/node/worker-bundle.js:22322:42)
         at InterceptingListener.module.exports.InterceptingListener.onReceiveStatus (/azure-functions-host/workers/node/worker-bundle.js:22372:8)
         at /azure-functions-host/workers/node/worker-bundle.js:22881:18
```

This issue is different than `Error: 14`, this one is Error 13 which is related to the response while `Error 14` is related to connection to the azure portal from VS Code.

Comment: Do edit the question with `code` and `versions` of **Node.js** and **Azure functions host** to debug this error.

Comment: You can also open an issue on GitHub: [azure-functions-host](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host) or [azure-functions-nodejs-worker](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-nodejs-worker)

Comment: Have you gone through this link which have a resolutions steps and a related conversation https://github.com/grpc/grpc-node/issues/1022